# Is there a simple way to shrink displayed equations and aligned equations to a percentage of the textwidth?

Tags: equations, align, resize

I'm writing my linear algebra lecture notes in `beamer`. Often, I want to display an equation involving large matrices, but the equation will not fit the width of the available space in the slide.

Is there a simple way to shrink these equations? I'm looking for a solution that works with both displayed equation environments and `align` environments.

I've tried the package `resizegather` but this has been quite buggy.

Comment: The `nccmath` package defines medium-sized commands (~ 80% of `\displaystyle`) (`\mfrac,\medint,  \medmath`) and environments (`medsize`, `mmatrix`). See whether it is sufficiently shrinked.

Comment: General solution is given in @Bernard comment. For particular one please provide an example of your slide (in form of compilable small document) with equation with which you have problem to fit on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\resizebox` (graphicx package) to shrink overlarge equations (among other things), but you first need to put them into a variable width box.  Varwidth won't do it (I tried).

Of course you could just use a minipage with a larger (predetermined) width,  especially if you intend to add equation numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\def\arraystretch{1.4}% local to box
$\begin{array}{@{}>{\displaystyle}r<{\null}@{}>{\displaystyle\null}l@{}}
 A &= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} \\
 B &\neq 0
\end{array}$}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]